# why does if name == ("Alice' or "Bob"): not work in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote simple program as below:

```
name = input("enter your name\n")
if name == ("Alice" or "Bob"):
    print ("Hello" + ' ' + name)
```

The question is why does the above program does not give expected result when I input `Bob`

Comment: Have you noticed your code has a syntax error ? `if name == ("Alice" ...`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Can you please give me some links.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this :

```
if name == ("Alice" or "Bob")
```

it will first evaluate ("Alice" or "Bob"), as it is between parenthesis... then compare it to name...

if you do :

```
if (name == "Alice") or (name == "Bob")
```

then it will evaluate correctly

Comment: sorry, not the best with Python, but would a better approach not be `if name in ["Alice","Bob"]`?

Comment: @AlexanderHolman's approach is more "pythonic" and also you don't need the parenthesis. ``if name == "Alice" or name == "Bob"`` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah sorry... I'm more used to vb .net actually (not my fault, they use it at work...)

Answer (score -1):

if you run `x = ("Alice" or "Bob")`, x evaluates to "Alice" that is why "Bob" does not work.
Solution:

```
if name == "Alice" or name == "Bob":
   print("Hello", name)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `if name in ("Alice", "Bob"):`

Comment: @BAH is there a difference between normal backets `()` and square `[]`?

Comment: @AlexanderHolman yes, these are different data structures - normal parenthesis define a `tuple` (immutable), and square brackets define a `list` (mutable).